# Thread in python not working

Tags: python, multithreading

What I need to do is to run a same set of commands again and again to more than 1 device. But I need to do it simultaneously. 1-3 second interval before sending the set of commands to other devices is fine. So I thought of using thread.

Here's how the code goes.

```
class UseThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, devID):
        super(UseThread, self).__init__()
        ... other commands ....
        ... other commands ....
        ... other commands ....

   file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\Samples.txt','r')

   while 1:
       line = file.readline()
       if not line:
           print 'Done!'
           break
       for Code in cp.options('code'):
           line = cp.get('product',Code)
           line = line.split(',')
           for devID in line:
               t=UseThread(devID)
               t.start()
```

It was able to run and record result for the first trial across all devices, but for 2nd trial, it hangs somewhere in the code where it says "Monkey Command : wake"

what is wrong with the thread that makes it behave this way?

Comment: how do you invoke the thread? your threaded code should be inside the function `run(self):`

Comment: Read some on tutorials on Python threading module. You didn't catch the basics yet.

Comment: @vikki like  this. t=UseThread(devID) t.start() . the threaded code is inside the useThread Class itself ( and it contains a lot of methods). So you mean what I did is wrong?

Comment: When you call `t.start()`, the method `t.run()` is executed on a new thread. So put you code inside it. You can call other methods from there, but this is your starting point.

Comment: Do what Thorsten says, and make sure you call `t.start()` and not `t.run()` otherwise the code will not run on a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the threaded code has to be in the `run()` method.

whatever is in the `__init__()` method, will be called before setting up the thread, when the new object is created (so it's part of the calling thread).

```
class UseThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, devID):
        super(UseThread, self).__init__()
        self.devID = devID
    def run(self):
        ## threaded stuff ....
        ## threaded stuff ....
        pass

## ...
for devID in line:
   t=UseThread(devID) # this calls UseThread.__init__()
   t.start()          # this creates a new thread that will run UseThread.run()
```